# Depth vs Position

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl, depth-buffer

I've been reading about reconstructing a fragment's position in world space from a depth buffer, but I was thinking about storing position in a high-precision three channel position buffer. Would doing this be faster than unpacking the position from a depth buffer? What is the cost of reconstructing position from depth?

Comment: Maybe I am missing a detail or perhaps it was omitted, but position, in I am assuming in 3 dimensional space is not the same as depth which is a 1 dimensional space. You cannot reconstruct a 3d coordinate from 1 dimensional data. Its like asking where I live, and I respond 20 miles from the airport. 20 miles which way... In 2d space, depth is equal to the radius of a circle.

Comment: @mwjohnson You can reconstruct position from depth, given the inverse projection matrix and coordinates of the sample location on the depth texture. Sorry I didn't make myself clear. It's done sometimes in deferred shading.

Comment: On a desktop GPU, reconstructing position from depth is your best bet. All the commercial graphics engines do it that way, it saves a hell of a lot of memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is essentially unanswerable for two reasons:

1. There are several ways of "reconstructing position from depth", with different performance characteristics.
2. It is *very* hardware-dependent.

The last point is important. You're essentially comparing the performance of a texture fetch of a `GL_RGBA16F` (at a minimum) to the performance of a `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` fetch followed by some ALU computations. Basically, you're asking if the cost of fetching an addition 32-bits per fragment (the difference between the 24x8 fetch and the RGBA16F fetch) is equivalent to the ALU computations.

That's going to change with various things. The performance of fetching memory, texture cache sizes, and so forth will all have an effect on texture fetch performance. And the speed of ALUs depends on how many are going to be in-flight at once (ie: number of shading units), as well as clock speeds and so forth.

In short, there are far too many variables here to *know* an answer a priori.

That being said, consider history.

In the earliest days of shaders, back in the GeForce 3 days, people would need to re-normalize a normal passed from the vertex shader. They did this by using a *cubemap*, not by doing math computations on the normal. Why? Because it was faster.

Today, there's pretty much *no* common programmable GPU hardware, in the desktop or mobile spaces, where a cubemap texture fetch is faster than a dot-product, reciprocal square-root, and a vector multiply. Computational performance in the long-run outstrips memory access performance.

So I'd suggest going with history and finding a [quick means of computing it in your shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space).

Comment: Yeah, I remember being laughed at after I left the industry for a while and asked whatever happened to normalization cubemaps :) We've come a long way. Looking back on it, it is kind of funny that the expense of fetching from a lookup texture was so much less than a pretty important operation (series of instructions including `DP3`, `RSQ` and `MUL`).